# Open Excel workbook in full screen mode

Tags: excel

I have an Excel workbook that I want to open in Full screen mode.
This workbook should open with a password lock(Which I will implement) upon double-clicking the file.

Is there a way I can open the Excel workbook in something like 'Kiosk' mode
I don't want any toolbars,Ribon interfaces,Statusbars,Cell select indicators(see below) ...
[image: Cell select indicators]

I am also looking towards locking ALL cells,so they cant be edited

Security wise,is there a way to truly protect a document.
For instance,I am looking at securing this file so that it cant be opened in any other computer,Something like a unique hash.

Looking forward to hear your ideas.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out 80 % of my requirement from the macro code below

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate() 
    On Error Resume Next 
    With Application 
        .DisplayFullScreen = False 
        .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = True 
    End With

End Sub

In addition to this,I have Hid the Gridlines,Heading and Formula Bar.

What I only need to do is hide the status and title bar(where it shows title.xlx)

How can I hide these both.
Can you write a macro that performs these 2 tasks and merge it with the existing macro seen above

thanks,